# Unable to install PIL in virtual env using pip

Tags: macos, gcc, virtualenv, pip

I'm using a OSX 10.9 and I'm trying to install Pil in a virtualenv using pip. I keep getting the the following error message:

"unable to execute usr/local/bin/gcc/: No such file or directory
error: command 'usr/local/bin/gcc/' failed with exit status 1"

If I type gcc -v in command line I get
"Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix" I have uninstalled XCode 5.1 and installed only command line tools as I don't use XCode but still get the error msg when I try to install Pil. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Note the path difference:

```
"unable to execute usr/local/bin/gcc/: No such file or directory error: command 'usr/local/bin/gcc/' failed with exit status 1" 
                   ^---missing /
```

Since there's no leading `/`, it's a relative path, looking for a `usr/local/bin` path UNDER wherever you're running this build script from.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/gcc/" and run pip install pil afterwards and I still get the error.

Comment: Hi, I've been able to resolve this issue by running the following commands in terminal:- "export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments" and "export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments"